# How to change the paintcomponent in JPanel from a button panel in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, panel

I am having a hard time figuring out how I can change the color of a paint component within a DrawPanel.

The method we need to use is that the color of the paint component can be changed via a ButtonPanel.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the handler to recognize the panel and change it's color.

How to change the paintcomponent in JPanel from a button panel in java

**main.java**

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                new Window();
            }           
        });     
    }
}
```

**Window.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window () {
        // `super ' calls a function inherited from the parent class ( JFrame )
        super();
        setTitle("Callbacks");
        setSize (new Dimension(420, 350));

        // Make sure the window appears in the middle of your screen
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Determines what should happen when the frame is closed
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Chooses a certain layout type for the elements in this frame
        getContentPane().setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        // TODO : add elements to the content pane
        DrawPanel dp = new DrawPanel ();
        ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel ();

        // Places the DrawPanel in the center of the frame
        getContentPane (). add (dp , BorderLayout . CENTER );
        // Places the ButtonPanel in the top of the frame
        getContentPane (). add (bp , BorderLayout . NORTH );


        // Set the window to visible ! Yup ... This is necessary
        setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

**DrawPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private Color color;

    public DrawPanel(){
        super();
        color = Color.BLACK ;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillRect(100 , 30, 200 , 200);
    }

}
```

**ButtonPanel.java**

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {


    public ButtonPanel () {
        super ();
        // Add a button to the panel . The argument to the JButton constructor
        // will become the text on the button .
        JButton b = new JButton ("Change color!");
        JButton c = new JButton ("Test");
        add (b);
        add (c);
        b.addActionListener(new InputHandler());

    }
}
```

**InputHandler**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;

public class InputHandler implements ActionListener {

    public InputHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO : add code here that will
        // be ran when the button is clicked
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me or send me in the right direction.

Comment: The major problem is that the code is extending components when there is no real need to do so. This applies to both `Window` & `ButtonPanel` (though there is a logical case for extending `DrawPanel`).

Comment: Yeah it's a part of the assignment I'm working on. When I was looking for answers they didn't extend either.

Comment: Bind the two together through a mutual contract (ie an `interface`) which represents the data you want to share, provide an observer pattern in the contract so that interested parties can monitor for changes to the data and update themselves

Answer (score 0):

Make them friends to each other so that the `Listener` will know the `Panel`:

```
// Window
DrawPanel dp = new DrawPanel ();
ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel (dp); // pass panel to button
```

then:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {       
    public ButtonPanel (DrawPanel d) {
        super ();
        // Add a button to the panel . The argument to the JButton constructor
        // will become the text on the button .
        JButton b = new JButton ("Change color!");
        JButton c = new JButton ("Test");
        add (b);
        add (c);
        b.addActionListener(new InputHandler(d)); // pass panel to listener    
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class InputHandler implements ActionListener {
    DrawPanel d;
    public InputHandler(DrawPanel d) {
        this.d = d;
    }    
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        d.setColor(Color.BLUE); // whatever
        d.repaint(); // force painting
    }
}
```

then:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {   
    private Color color;    
    public DrawPanel(){
        super();
        color = Color.BLACK ;
    }
    public void setColor(Color c) {
        this.color = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillRect(100 , 30, 200 , 200);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

One last question regarding this project, is it possible to change the shape on a button press? Do I have to use the paint component?

Comment: Of course, then the shape should be described externally to `paintComponent`